# junit 4 all pairwise permutations of test methods

Tags: unit-testing, junit, junit4, testcase, test-suite

i have a [test case](http://xunitpatterns.com/Testcase%20Class.html) that has n [test methods](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Method.html), one of the test methods fails when the test case is run. and this failing test method succeeds when run by itself.

i would like to dynamically (at run time) create a set of [test suites](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Suite%20Object.html) (or test cases), one for each pair of test methods in the test case.

so a test case with 3 test methods would generate 3!=6 test suites (or test cases).

thanks

Comment: Wouldn't you rather figure out why it's failing in the multi-test situation?

Comment: running all pairs of tests may help one do that.